# ios7 toolbar color washed out

Tags: ios7, uitoolbar

In iOS 7, if I set the toolbar background color, it uses a washed out version of the color, not the actual color. At first I thought maybe the toolbar was semi-transparent (not fully opaque) but that doesn't appear to be the problem.

Even using black only give me a light grey color.

```
[topToolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

I also tried:

```
[topToolbar setTranslucent:NO];
```

But that just caused my toolbar color to be ignored completely.

Anybody know how to make it just use the color specified, without any weirdness?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the setBarTintColor method previously, but it is what is needed to accomplish this.

```
[topToolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[topToolbar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: Right answer but there is no need to set the translucency property